# Ubuntu 14.04 wont login

Tags: unity, gnome, login, lightdm, xrdp

I have tried this

Method1:

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install lightdm

dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Method2:

```
ls -ld /tmp
```

Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should read exactly so:

```
drwxrwxrwt
```

Method3:

```
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak
```

Method4:

Reset ubuntu-desktop; unity; gnome; Create another admin account

Still all this 4 methods fail for me. I was trying to set XRDP and part of the setting is to create sessions and desktop enviroment. I do remember doing a syntax command that give a big error `echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession`but instead i did type `sudo xfce4-session >~/.xsession` since then cant login.

Comment: I don't follow your question sorry, but the `sudo xfce4.. >~/.xses` may not have done what you expected.. You elevated permissions so you may need change ownership back to you (ie. use `chmod`)

Comment: How far into the login do you get?

Comment: IM not a pro linux user and login is like it were in loop mode thats how far it is